# Getting user role in Team or channel

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I have a Microsoft Teams group tab and I'd like to implement a permission system in which users can do different things in the tab depending on their role in the team (or channel). The context I get from the Teams JavaScript API cannot be trusted, so I have to check group/team/channel role through the MS Graph API.

The only way I've found to check whether a user is an owner or only a member of a team is to call `/teams/{groupId}/channels/{channelId}/members`. In the response I can see which roles users have and I so I can find out if the current user has owner privileges.

The problem is that this endpoint requires admin consent (I guess because it displays data of other users). I'd like to avoid having to ask for admin consent, however. Is there another way of finding out about the **role** of a user in a team without admin consent? (As private channels behave differently in Teams, this would be the same as finding out about the role in a channel)

I know that I can get **if** a user is in a group through the optional group claims that are added to the ID token but this doesn't include the rule inside the group/team/channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read a user's role in a channel currently requires admin consent, the permission needed is `ChannelMember.Read.All` see list conversation member documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/conversationmember-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). Admin consent is also required to get a member of a team or list members in a team. For your particular use case, I would recommend asking your admin to grant these permissions.